# Convergence in probability of random variables and continuous function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, statistics

I want to prove that if $\xi_n \xrightarrow {\mathbb{P}} \xi$ and for some continuous function $\mathit{f}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ then $$\mathit{f}(\xi_n)\xrightarrow {\mathbb{P}} \mathit{f}(\xi)$$
May somebody can help me? I would be grateful.

Comment: maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288628/continuous-mapping-theorem-for-random-variables/2030156

Comment: What if $\xi_n \stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} 0$ and $f(x) = 1/x?$

Comment: @BruceET then the statement is not applicable I think, since $f$ should be continuous (on $\mathbb{R}$)...

Comment: How is $f(x)= 1/x$ not continuous? I think you need more explicit conditions. Maybe google 'Slutsky's Theorem', of which this seems to be a special case..

Comment: @BruceET but the function $f$ should be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, which $1/x$ isn't; and even if we define some value at $0$, $f$ won't be continuous at $0$...

Comment: Here is a bit more general result: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044433/convergence-in-probability-of-random-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition of continuity, let  $\varepsilon > 0$, then ther exists $\delta >0$ s.t. $\lvert X_n - X \rvert \leq \delta \implies \lvert f(X_n) - f(X) \rvert \leq \varepsilon$ or equivalently (taking the negation of previous statement), $\lvert f(X_n) - f(X) \rvert > \varepsilon \implies \lvert X_n - X \rvert > \delta$. Then by inclusion of events, $\mathbb{P}(\lvert f(X_n) - f(X) \rvert > \varepsilon) \leq \mathbb{P}(\lvert X_n - X \rvert > \delta)$ and the last quantity goes to $0$ as $n\to \infty$ by definition of convergence in probability.

Comment: $f$ is not necessarily uniformly continuous. However, a continuous function is uniformly continuous on compact sets.